# selenium grid running code on just 1 node,not all

Tags: c#, selenium, grid

I have set up Selenium grid on 1 hub and 2 nodes. They do connect and register well. But when i run the code from hub, only 1 node runs the code, other one does nothing.

I have tried RemoteWebDriver and i am putting the hub id in there

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));//hub id goes here

it only runs on 1 node!
what should i use to run it on 2nd node as well

Comment: plus, its random.Sometimes it runs on only node 1, and sometimes only on node 2

Comment: If you run tests one by one it will runs on one node only. To use two nodes you need to start run you tests is parallel.

Comment: how to run tests in parallel? can i get some example please?

Comment: What test framework did you use? NUnit? MSTest? XUnit?

Comment: I use c#, visual studio, Nunit

Comment: You should look at NUnit documentation about parallel work: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution

Comment: But you need to always remember that tests the are executed parallel can influence each other. So they must written with think about it

Comment: cool, just tried making it parrallelized using NUnit..it says :Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point... some places say it is because of version of c#? not saure what version should i use:

Comment: namespace ParallelGrid
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class ParallelGrid1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
        }    }
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class ParallelGrid2
    {       [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
}}}

Comment: What project type do you have?

Comment: In project properties change your output type to "Class Library"

Comment: Cheers this worked :D it is running 2 browsers in parallel !

Comment: ok now i am writing these lines for remote web driver, it is still running node 1 tests only and not the node 2 tests                                                  
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that your tests i parallel now? Mb you create RemoteWebDriver in base class? Or directly in test class? And also why there is wb/hub endpoint in your url? As I remember it's not need to add this, and even more this is UI endpoint. You need just socket there (ip + port)

Comment: Lets say i have to open google in 2 browsers, serch Test1 in 1st, search Test 2 in 2nd. It opens 2 browsers, writes Test1Test2 in one browser and pass the test. how do i get around it?

Comment: namespace ParallelGrid
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class ParallelGrid1
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
          [SetUp]
           public void Setup()
           {
             driver = new ChromeDriver();
           }

        [Test]
        [Parallelizable]
        public void Test1()
        {
         
            go to google write test 1
        }

        [Test]
        [Parallelizable]          
            public void Test2()
            {
                
               go to google write test 2

            }

Comment: Your `IWebDriver driver;` is shared with both threads. Just make it `static` and mark it with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute so both threads will get their own copy of field.

Comment: Hi Lemm, this is resolved and working perfectly both cross browser and cross platform! Thank you :)